# property attachshadow does not exist on type element

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I created a new visual studio project with type Typescript with html application , I am trying to create a shadow dom but there is an error.

```
class Append{
    element: HTMLElement;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this.element = element;
    }


window.onload = () => {
    var el = document.getElementById('content');
    let shadow = el.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
}
```

> property attachshadow does not exist on type element

Answer (score 15):

Not all elements can accept a Shadow DOM.

The list of authorized HTML elements is defined in the [`attachShadow()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attachshadow) definition in the Shadow DOM v1 specification:

> valid custom element name, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<blockquote>`, `<body>`, `<div>`, `<footer>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`, `<main>`, `<nav>`, `<p>`, `<section>` or `<span>`

Comment: Is it not possible to add shadow root to a custom element? I am seeing some chrome extension adding #shadow-root (open) under a tag <grammarly-extension>

Comment: @NathanB it is definitely possible to add shadow root to custom element. The list provided by this answer includes "valid custom element name" as the first item on the list. See this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) which seems a bit more up-to-date than the one this answer uses

Comment: @NathanB It's the Grammarly extension. Try removing it from your browser