# shadow dom not attaching on class that inherit from HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to attach shadow dom to this but it does not attach and gives a error DOMExpection operation is not supported but when inherit from HTMLElement or HTMLSpanElement it works!
So question is can i attach shadow dom to this when inherit from HTMLButtonElement if yes then how else not why!
here is my code :-

```js
class Home_Button extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._dom = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.createButton();
  }

  createButton() {
    this.classList.add("contents");
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `
      .sentToHome{
        margin: 1%;
        padding: 1%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      .homeLink{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: green;
      }
    `;
    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.innerText = "<< Home";
    anchor.setAttribute("href", "/");
    anchor.setAttribute("class", "homeLink");
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("class", "sentToHome");
    button.appendChild(anchor);
    this._dom.append(style, button);
  }
}

customElements.define("simple-btn", Home_Button, { extends: "button" });
const sentToHomeBtn = new Home_Button();
document.body.appendChild(sentToHomeBtn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ***@danny-365csi-engelman*** is also right but
I found this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380552/19220606)

According to the answer we can attach shadow dom on few elements and button does not exits in those elements.

I just inherit from **HTMLElement** class instead of *HTMLButtonElement* class.
After that everything works fine!.

If you want to check current source code go [here.](https://github.com/YashLodhi-16/Local/blob/master/Web_Development/PROJECTS/PROJECT_14/public/js/utilityFunctions/gotoHomePage.js)

Answer (score 0):

This will never work in Safari, because Apple has, since 2016, stated they will never implement Customized Built-In Elements, they have only implemented `extends HTMLElement`

Trigger `createButton` from the `connectedCallback`; you can't do DOM operations in the `constructor` (besides shadowDOM content) because the element (`this`) doesn't exist in the DOM yet.

Also note `this._dom` isn't required, you get `this.shadowRoot` for free from `attachShadow()`

To be clear `this.classList` is the problem